# Can I make a List of a subclass without knowing which subclass it is?

Tags: java, generics, subclass

I want to do something like this:

```
public List<?> queryProducts (String type) {
    Product p = Product.getProductByType(type);
    List response = null;
    if (p instanceof Dishwasher)
        response = new ArrayList<Dishwasher>();
    if (p instanceof Refrigerator)
        response = new ArrayList<Refrigerator>();
    // ...and so on

    return response;
}
```

How can I do this without going through every subclass?  Is there something like this?

```
List<classOf(p)> response = new ArrayList<classOf(p)>();
```

Comment: Have you tried with `ArrayList<p.class>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of accepting the `String` type, accept a `Class` parameter with a generic type parameter.

```
public <P extends Product> List<P> queryProducts (Class<P> clazz) {

    List<P> response = new ArrayList<P>();
    ...
    return response;
}
```

The caller can execute

```
Product p = Product.getProductByType(type);
```

to get the object, and then call `getClass()` to pass in the `Class` necessary.

Comment: Your method signature is not valid

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work, although I'm not sure I understand why this is valid and "List<p.getClass()> response" is not.

Comment: Java Generics is available at compile-time only.  Type erasure occurs when creating the bytecode, meaning that the generic type information isn't available at runtime.  Therefore, you cannot use the result of a method call at runtime to specify a generic type parameter.  Generic type parameters must be available at compile time.

Comment: `p.getClass()` gives you the class of `p` at runtime. Generics are only available on compile time.

Answer (score 2):

Just create:

```
List<Product> response = new ArrayList<Product>();
```

and add items there in order to keep abstraction

Comment: Thanks for adding this, it's possible that I should be doing this instead, I will have to think about it.

Comment: Please read also awsome sun/oracle tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this in a typesafe way you have to use a `Class` parameter instead of a `String`

E.g.

```
public <T extends Product> List<T> queryProducts (Class<T> type) {
    Product p = Product.getProductByType(type); // needs change
    List response = new ArrayList<T>()
    ...    
    return response;
}
```

You can then call the method this way:

```
List<Refrigerator> list = queryProducts(Refrigerator.class);
```